# /bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip: not found

Tags: linux, opencv, ffmpeg

I am trying to compile FFmpeg for opencv-xilinx but i get an error like this

> /bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip: not found
>   ffbuild/library.mak:101: recipe for target
>   'install-libavdevice-shared' failed make: ***
>   [install-libavdevice-shared] Error 127

What can i do any thoughts

before i make install i get a warning.

> ```
> WARNING: arm-Linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
> ```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: You seem to cross compile, is the path to your cross compiler in the PATH environment variable?

Comment: Yes it is the PATH but it cannot find i dont understand

Answer (score 1):

The binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi package solved the issue for me, run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it got resolved only when I did `sudo ln -s /<path to binary>/arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip "/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip"`